# How can I get values of elements from remote webpages using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

Guys,
I'm noob and I wanted to write a local vbscript to get some values from a remote webpage.
There are some snippets of the webpage.

```
<div id="profile_content" class="dxb_bc">
    <div>
        <div class="hm">
            <p>
                <a href="space-uid-52433.html" target="_blank">
                    <img src="http://bbs.dealmoon.com/uc_server/avatar.php?uid=52433&size=middle" />
                </a>
            </p>
            <h2 class="mbn">
                <a href="space-uid-52433.html" target="_blank">LittleCar</a>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="xl xl2 cl ul_list">
            <li class='ul_ignore'>
                <a href="home.php?mod=spacecp&ac=friend&op=ignore&uid=52433&handlekey=ignorefriendhk_52433" id="a_ignore_52433" onclick="showWindow(this.id, this.href, 'get', 0);">AAAAAA</a>
            </li>
            <li class='ul_msg'>
                <a href="home.php?mod=space&uid=52433&do=wall">BBBBBB</a>
            </li>
            <li class='ul_poke'>
                <a href="home.php?mod=spacecp&ac=poke&op=send&uid=52433&handlekey=propokehk_52433" id="a_poke_52433" onclick="showWindow(this.id, this.href, 'get', 0);">CCCCCC</a>
            </li>
            <li class='ul_pm'>
                <a href="home.php?mod=spacecp&ac=pm&op=showmsg&handlekey=showmsg_52433&touid=52433&pmid=0&daterange=2" id="a_sendpm_52433" onclick="showWindow('showMsgBox', this.href, 'get', 0)">DDDDDD</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is very easy. I just wanted to get the value 'LittleCar' 'AAAAAA' 'BBBBBB' and so on. I tried to write vbscript to capture the element :

```
<a href="space-uid-52433.html" target="_blank">LittleCar</a>
```

like this：

```
IEApp.Document.getElementById("profile_content").getElementByTagName("a").Item(1)
```

but I got an error something like unsupported method. What I can do is just to get the element by id in vbscript. I haven't found anything valued for solving my question. So I'm here.

I've already asked a similar question which is put on hold. My reputation has been decreased by 2 for that. I cannot believe there's no one can help me. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Get the collection of A tags with

```
' Note the "s" in getElementsByTagName
Set collATags = IEApp.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
'                                        ^ there it is
```

Now you can iterate over them like:

```
For Each aTag in collATags
    Wscript.Echo aTag.outerHtml
Next
```

**EDIT:**

To get a specific text like AAAAA, use the innerHtml property:

```
For Each aTag in collATags
    If aTag.innerHtml = "AAAAA" then
        '  Found it!
        Set foundTag = aTag
        Exit for
    End if
Next
```

To narrow down to a specific tag from an tag with an ID you can use this:

```
Set profileContentElement = document.GetElementById("profile-content")
```

Use this element to get all elements with a tag name:

```
Set collATags = profileContentElement.getElementsByTagName("a")
```

And use the method described above to iterate through the elements to get the one with the AAAAA text as innerHtml

**EDIT2:**

In order to get the element with an identifier that is not `id`, get the parent element with the correct ID, get the childcollection on Tagname and filter the correct element on outerHtml:

```
' Get the correct parent
Set profileContentElement = document.GetElementById("profile-content")

' Get the childcollection with the A tag
Set collATags = profileContentElement.getElementsByTagName("a")

' Iterate through the collection
Set foundTag = Nothing
For Each aTag in collATags
    If aTag.outerHtml = "home.php?mod=space&uid=52433&do=wall" then
        '  Found it!
        Set foundTag = aTag
        Exit for
    End if
Next

' Get the text in the foundTag
If not foundTag Is Nothing Then
    wscript.echo "Woei, found the linktext, it is: " & foundTag.innerHtml
End If
```

note: No Windows machine here, this is untested code.

Comment: Thx. I understand the use of iteration. But if I want to get only 'AAAAAA', how should I do?

Comment: if I use the iteration of the specific tag, it will take so long time to get the value. Is there any methods to quickly locate the tag and get its value? Thx

Comment: If I wanted to get the value which I didn't know, what should I do? e.g., <a href="home.php?mod=space&uid=52433&do=wall">BBBBBB</a> I wanted to echo the value 'BBBBBB', can I get the value by some methods such as getElementByXXX.innerHTML?

Comment: @franksunnn; What do you _do_ know of that link? Is it always the fourth link -> Get the fourth element. Does it always contain the string `&do=wall` -> Get the outerHtml of the `A` tags, see if it contains this string and get the innerHtml of that link. You need an unique identifier to define what link you want, you cannot say _"Give me some link that I know that is right, but the script has to guess"_.

Comment: If I want to use "home.php?mod=space&uid=52433&do=wall" as the unique identifier, what should I do? :)

Comment: @franksunnn, see the seconds edit. Try to understand what the code does so this is not a "SHOW ME THE CODEZ!" question.

Comment: This is a gem of an answer!!....I was searching for hours and got the answer here. Thank you :)