# VBScript locate specific tag quickly and get its value

Tags: vbscript, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I wanted to get some value from remote webpage by using local VBScript.
Until now what I could do was to iterate the tag, locate it and get its value.
However, I found it was not inefficient and it took kind of long time. So is there any method to make the VBScript more efficient?
Here are my source HTML and vbscripts, I wanted to get the value 'BBBBBB'.
Source HTML：

```
<div id="profile_content" class="dxb_bc">
    <div>
        <div class="hm">
            <p>
                <a href="space-uid-52433.html" target="_blank">
                    <img src="http://bbs.dealmoon.com/uc_server/avatar.php?uid=52433&size=middle" />
                </a>
            </p>
            <h2 class="mbn">
                <a href="space-uid-52433.html" target="_blank">LittleCar</a>
            </h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="xl xl2 cl ul_list">
            <li class='ul_ignore'>
                <a href="home.php?mod=spacecp&ac=friend&op=ignore&uid=52433&handlekey=ignorefriendhk_52433" id="a_ignore_52433" onclick="showWindow(this.id, this.href, 'get', 0);">AAAAAA</a>
            </li>
            <li class='ul_msg'>
                <a href="home.php?mod=space&uid=52433&do=wall">BBBBBB</a>
            </li>
            <li class='ul_poke'>
                <a href="home.php?mod=spacecp&ac=poke&op=send&uid=52433&handlekey=propokehk_52433" id="a_poke_52433" onclick="showWindow(this.id, this.href, 'get', 0);">CCCCCC</a>
            </li>
            <li class='ul_pm'>
                <a href="home.php?mod=spacecp&ac=pm&op=showmsg&handlekey=showmsg_52433&touid=52433&pmid=0&daterange=2" id="a_sendpm_52433" onclick="showWindow('showMsgBox', this.href, 'get', 0)">DDDDDD</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

VBScript snippets:

```
Set objDoc = IE.Document
Set allTags = objDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each aTag in allTags
    If aTag.innerHTML = "BBBBBB"
        'dosomething
    End If
Next
```

Thx

Comment: You could filter by the class of the `<li class='ul_msg'>`.. would get it faster.. but why don't you use js or jquery?

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes I'm not coding a webpage. I'm just writing a local vbs to test a webpage. That's all :) How could I filter the class? There is not such a method named like 'getElementByClassName' in vbs.

Comment: I don't think there is a `getElementByClassName` but you could first do `getElementById('profile_content')` then do the for each loop. This would limit it from the whole page to just the <a> links within profile_content

Comment: Could by an idea use the `getElementById()`. You Could also try to use the method listed at the final post of this page [link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?536594-getElementsByClassName-Method). I don't know if will really help, but you can to adapt the code to your scope.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get values of elements from remote webpages using vbscript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243810/how-can-i-get-values-of-elements-from-remote-webpages-using-vbscript)