# Need to search for ISBN number on website and extract results to Excel

Tags: excel, search, automation, isbn

I have a school project to do - I have a list of books which I need to find on the following website: [www.arbookfind.co.uk](http://www.arbookfind.co.uk)
Once found, I need to select information contained in the result and transfer it to an excel spreadsheet so the books can be banded against certain criteria. 
I am really struggling and wondering if anyone has any ideas where I could start. Looking for resources to help me if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Either you do it in directly in VBSCRIPT in a VBA Macro under Excel, either you can use a software like httrack (or any other) to collect the values you need from the web and save them in the format you need.

A similar question was posted here for VBScript.

[How can I get values of elements from remote webpages using vbscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243810/how-can-i-get-values-of-elements-from-remote-webpages-using-vbscript)

Comment: Great, thank you for your help. I'll take a look. Thanks again, it's very much appreciated.